# Protecting API URL Data from being seen. cURL?

Tags: api, curl, deployd

How can we password protect our Deployd data accessed via URL?
Currently our users' data is visible on oursite.com/users.  How can we make it password protected so that only we,the site developers, can see our users' data via oursite.com/users?  (This is my first API and Deployd app.)
Many, many thanks!

I found the following, if any of these look like they would work:
    https://www.npmjs.com/package/dpd-curl-proxy
     https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-oauth

Comment: Learn about authentication. dpd-curl-proxy is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @SLaks Thanks for the reply!  I did some research, and will continue.  Would this be it?  https://www.npmjs.com/package/dpd-token-auth

Comment: You will also need to check whether the user is authorized in your code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try in your 'get' event

   if (!me)

   cancel('You donot have  access');

This will restrict 'users' -resource  from accessed without login.

2. To restrict access to certain user group - Use roles. 
   That will look like,

   if (!me && !me.Admin)
    cancel('You donot have  access');

You can try MARS CMS https://github.com/moorthi07/MarsCMS as boilerplate to rapid learning or prototype. This covers lots of Deployd's features like authentication , authorization, REST calls, ngResource examples.